# gameObject.transform.localScale ignores my material assignment on the game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I have a shield that I would like to shrink when a button is held down, and then when the button is released, the shield returns to it's original size. I would like the shield to be a translucent red color, so I attached a material to it in the inspector.

My code for shrinking the shield works as expected, however on every subsequent button press, the shield shows up as translucent grey instead of translucent red.

I am absolutely tearing my hair out over this. Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
if (Input.GetButton ("PS_Circle")) {

        playerOneShield.SetActive (true);

        playerOneShieldOn = true;

        playerOneShield.transform.position = playerOne.transform.position;

        playerOneShield.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.1F, 0.1f, 0);

    } else if (Input.GetButtonUp ("PS_Circle")) {

        playerOneShield.SetActive (false);

        playerOneShieldOn = false;

        playerOneShield.transform.localScale = new Vector3(45F, 50f, 0);
    }
```

Comment: what is the original code that set the shield color?

Comment: I don't use any code for assigning the material to the shield. I do it all through the inspector.